# AngularJS routeprovider with named groups stop multiple instance of controller

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

When i setup a routeprovider that contains a named group via `.when('/search/:searchString', {` when the page is loaded for each different `:searchString` it loads a new instance of the controller assigned.

This causes me a problem when i have a `$rootScope.$on('searchUpdated',` becuase it reacts to the broadcast message on every instance of the controller.

Is there a way to make it only load one controller and use the same controller for each request, if not is there a way to destroy the controller when the page has left.

Comment: The controller is probably destroyed, but listeners registered on the `$rootScope` don't go anywhere, since the `$rootScope` is never destroyed. You should post more code, but the problem seems to be your registering a listener on the `$rootScope` from **every** controller instance.

Comment: You where right on the money there. I had it on rootScope :S so easy to overlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>For anyone facing a similar issue:</sub>

The controller is destroyed, but listeners registered on the `$rootScope` still exist, since the `$rootScope` is never destroyed.

The problem seems to be your registering a listener on the `$rootScope` from every controller instance.